# My form_for [post, comment] is submitting to the wrong url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form_for in my application that is submitting to the wrong url.

```
          <% @posts.each do |post| %>
          <form class="col-md-12">
            <% comment = post.comments.build %>
            <%= form_for [post, comment], :url => post_comments_path(post), html: {class: "col-md-12", method: "POST"} do |comment_fields| %>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= comment_fields.text_area :content, placeholder: "Write a comment...", class: "form-control", rows: "4" %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <a class="col-md-1" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <%= comment_fields.submit "Comment", class: "col-md-3 pull-right btn btn-primary" %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

Here are is my PostsController index method:

```
def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

    @posts = @user.posts

end
```

I am expecting it to go to `POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create`

but it is sending this request instead:

```
Started GET "/users/6/posts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=WgbO5FhAA0ZhXFdk%2FizEbqTVxg2HW9VDY7aUKQTLmy3qLXLC8EH9%2FKr0w53TcId2KYoJmU7uodCFJOIDufno8g%3D%3D&comment%5Bcontent%5D=qqqqqqqqqqqq111&commit=Comment"
```

Here are my routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
          logout GET    /logout(.:format)                      sessions#destroy
           login GET    /login(.:format)                       sessions#new
         session POST   /session(.:format)                     sessions#create
     new_session GET    /session/new(.:format)                 sessions#new
    edit_session GET    /session/edit(.:format)                sessions#edit
                 GET    /session(.:format)                     sessions#show
                 PATCH  /session(.:format)                     sessions#update
                 PUT    /session(.:format)                     sessions#update
                 DELETE /session(.:format)                     sessions#destroy
      post_likes GET    /posts/:post_id/likes(.:format)        likes#index
                 POST   /posts/:post_id/likes(.:format)        likes#create
   new_post_like GET    /posts/:post_id/likes/new(.:format)    likes#new
       edit_like GET    /likes/:id/edit(.:format)              likes#edit
            like GET    /likes/:id(.:format)                   likes#show
                 PATCH  /likes/:id(.:format)                   likes#update
                 PUT    /likes/:id(.:format)                   likes#update
                 DELETE /likes/:id(.:format)                   likes#destroy
   post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     comments#index
                 POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create
new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format) comments#new
    edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)           comments#edit
         comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                comments#show
                 PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)                comments#update
                 PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                comments#update
                 DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                comments#destroy
      user_posts GET    /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)        posts#index
                 POST   /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)        posts#create
```

Is there a way to do this with form_for? I could use a form_tag post_likes_path, with a method: delete option, but I want to automatically set the @comment.post_id to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't keep a `form` inside another `form`.
Try this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <% comment = post.comments.build %>
    <%= form_for [post, comment], :url => post_comments_path(post), html: {class: "col-md-12"} do |comment_fields| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= comment_fields.text_area :content, placeholder: "Write a comment...", class: "form-control", rows: "4" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <a class="col-md-1" href="#">Cancel</a>
            <%= comment_fields.submit "Comment", class: "col-md-3 pull-right btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
    <% end %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks I missed that I'll accept the answer when it lets me in a few minutes.